# Custom Segue NavBar Back Button

Tags: ios, segue

I want to use a custom segue from my destination view controller back to the source view controller using the "Back" button in the NavBar. Is this possible? I have not been able to find an answer anywhere.

So far, I connected a custom segue from the destination view controller back to the source view controller and add the code below. However, the back-button does not trigger my custom segue.

```
-(void)perform
{

    UIViewController *sourceViewController = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *destinationController = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
    transition.duration = 0.5;

    [sourceViewController.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [sourceViewController.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: It's good that it doesn't work, because a "back" segue needs to _pop_ not push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to customize the transition back from a pushed view controller as it is popped from the navigation stack is with a *custom transition*, a new feature in iOS 7. (Prior to iOS 7 this is basically impossible.)

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Also here is a complete example; it is for a tab bar controller, not a navigation controller, but the principle is exactly the same: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch06p292customAnimation1/ch19p620customAnimation1/AppDelegate.m

Comment: Page not found for the second link.Can you please give a small example.What I needed to do is to navigate(Push) to another controller and come back without animation.I have used custom segue for it and its not animating when going to the next class but when I come back its animating.I dont want it.please give some suggestion about it.